# Image not shown in TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a TextBlock I'm adding inlines to, some of which are images. This is for a Twitter application, so the images are emojis.

I have now encountered a strange issue where an emoji image is not displayed, but another emoji right next to the missing one works just fine. In the attached screenshot I'm using [Snoop](https://github.com/cplotts/snoopwpf) to look at the WPF structure, and as far as I can tell everything is identical for all the inline images. *(I would be surprised if they weren't, though, because they are all put into the TextBlock in the same way)*.

The image source points to an image that actually [does exist](https://abs.twimg.com/emoji/v2/72x72/1f602.png), so why isn't it displayed when the other emoji is displayed just fine?

Does anybody have any idea as to what can cause this strange issue?

[image]

For completion, this is the somewhat pseudo code that returns text with emojis as a list of `Inline`'s:

```
List<Inline> inlines =  new List<Inline>();

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, emojiPattern)) {
    Uri src = new Uri("URL_TO_EMOJI");
    InlineUIContainer cont = new InlineUIContainer(new Image {
        Source = new BitmapImage(src)
    });
    inlines.Add(cont);
}

return inlines;
```

**Update**

It seems this is a problem with many connections. My Twitter application displays various lists. If I put the user in the screenshot in a separate list, then I display only that list, the emojis are all displayed. If I display many other lists, and users, at the same time, the emoji problems reappears.

There is no difference if I use Twitters own emojis, or the CDN for Twemoji.

So apparently there seems to be some sort of limit as to how many separate images can be used. So how can this limit be extended, or even ignored?

Comment: Stupid question: maybe you see the upper left corner of your image? It can happens if you set `Stretch` to `None` and set `Width` and `Height` of the `Image` to 10 for example. Size of this image is 72x72. What size of other images in the same `TextBlock`?

Comment: @Maxim All the images use the 72x72 source, so it should be the same as for the other images that are working.

Comment: Can you provide minimal code to reproduce the issue? I mean real code, not a pseudo code.

Comment: @Maxim I have tried to just make a simple XAML textblock with a few Run and Image elements, but it works just fine there, of course. The same when I do it from code. So I'm sort of suspecting that it has to do with the application showing a lot of images in general, so maybe I'm reaching some sort of limit. It would be strange, though, that only this emoji image is affected.

Comment: Try for test to use only this image for every emoji.

Comment: Good suggestion. In most places the emoji is displayed correct. Unfortunately, in other places it is not displayed at all (with only an empty placeholder like in the screenshot above)

Comment: @Maxim In order to test my assumption that this was a connection limit of sorts, I also tried to change the source from which I get the emojis (now changed to Twemoji's official CDN), but the same problem remains with the same emoji. All other emojis are displayed correctly (so it seems, because I haven't found any empty spaces between content and emojis in other tweets)

Comment: Okay, after even more testing I'm leaning even more towards this being some sort of connection limit. If I have my app only display the tweets from the user is in the screenshot the emojis display correctly. If I have my app display tweets from many users in many different lists, the emojis are missing.

Comment: If its a connection limit, maybe you need to download the images into a list manually using a single connection / session instead of setting an URL as `Image.Source`. However, I don't *know* whether each URL setting is leading to a separate connection, I only suspect it.

Comment: Manually downloading the image, converting `byte[]` to BitmapImage, and setting this as `Image.Source` seems to work as I don't have any missing emojis any more. Thanks for all suggestions, and I'll write up a good answer (with caching) that I'll end up using.

Answer (score 1):

I never did find out about the connection limit, so I ended up downloading the images myself, and caching them so that I never download the same emoji more than once:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, BitmapImage> EmojiCache = new Dictionary<string, BitmapImage>();

private BitmapImage GetEmoji(string emojiCode) {
    if (EmojiCache.ContainsKey(emojiCode)) {
        return EmojiCache[emojiCode];
    }

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    byte[] emojiBytes = client.DownloadData($"https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/2/72x72/{emojiCode}.png");
    BitmapImage emojiImg = new BitmapImage();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(emojiBytes)) {
        ms.Position = 0;
        emojiImg.BeginInit();
        emojiImg.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
        emojiImg.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        emojiImg.UriSource = null;
        emojiImg.StreamSource = ms;
        emojiImg.EndInit();
    }

    EmojiCache.Add(emojiCode, emojiImg);

    return emojiImg;
}
```

If anybody knows more about any connection limits in WPF that could cause the main issue, feel free to leave a comment or an answer on how to extend it.

Comment: I wouldn't even be sure that the limit is WPF side... it might as well be the server protecting itself against a possible DOS attack, when to many connections are involved.

Comment: @grek40 I did suspect the server might have been the issue, but it was then strange that is was only regarding one special emoji. Besides, web browsers doesn't seem to have that problem when displaying many tweets on twitter.com, so I'm still not sure it was *only* the server protecting itself, though it may have been a contributing cause.

Comment: A web browser will most likely use the same connection / session for multiple requests. Actually I was a bit surprised to see you creating a new `WebClient` instance each time instead of downloading all emoji with the same instance.